# Efficiently limit the area to render graphics to on an HTML5 canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm looking for a way to render graphics onto an HTML5 canvas using JavaScript, but I want to *only render said graphics if they're inside a pre-defined mask.*

I'm creating a GUI framework that can be used to easily and quickly create GUIs on an HTML5 canvas. I think that something that would be really nice to have is a way to render graphics inside an element, and make the element auto-crop the graphics so that they always stay inside of it. For example, I can make a rectangular element and animate a circular pulse inside of it, and as the circle extends past the outside of the element, those parts of he circle should just not render to keep it looking smooth and sharp. This is similar to what CSS does with `overflow: hidden;`

Now, I know that one option is to use a mask-like feature. For example, P5.js has `mask()`. However, this is very very slow. Masking a single element a single time using P5.js significantly reduces framerate, and I want to be doing  this potentially hundreds of times per frame without frame drops. I know that CSS does this *incredibly* efficiently (from my own experience working with it), but I can't seem to think of any way to make it efficient on a canvas element.

I could do it pretty simply if it was just a rectangle, but I want to do this for *any* shape. For example, a circle, a star, a rectangle with rounded edges, or really any polygon at all.

How can this be done? I thought of potentially rendering to an off screen canvas (which is shrunken to the size of the element in question), then render the element onto that screen using one color (let's say the background color will be white, and the shape will be black), then rendering the image we want masked onto another off screen canvas that's the same width as our other OSC, then looping through one of their image data arrays and mapping one to the other based on whether said pixel is white or black on the mask canvas.
But........ I can't help but think that that's going to be *incredibly* slow for the computer to process. I assume that CSS somehow leverages the GPU to do this type of computation incredibly efficiently and that's why they get such an increase in performance. Is it possible for me to do the same or am I just dreaming?

---

Okay, so I have found two different means of doing this (huge thank you to @Kaiido). One method is to use `ctx.clip()` while one works with `CanvasPattern`.

This snippet shows both means in action:

```html
<canvas id = "c" width = "400" height = "400"></canvas>
        
<canvas id = "c2" width = "400" height = "400"></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,400);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(200,200,100,0,6);
  ctx.clip();

  ctx.beginPath();// This clears our previous arc from the path so that it doesn't render in when we `fill()`

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
  for(var i = 0;i < 20;i++){
    for(var j = 0;j < 40;j++){
      ctx.rect(i * 20 + j % 2 * 10,j * 10,10,10);
    }
  }
  ctx.fill();
</script>

<script>
  var canvas2 = document.getElementById("c2");
  var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

  ctx2.fillStyle = "orange";
  ctx2.fillRect(0,0,400,400);

  var osc = new OffscreenCanvas(400,400);
  var oscctx = osc.getContext("2d");

  oscctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
  for(var i = 0;i < 20;i++){
    for(var j = 0;j < 40;j++){
      oscctx.rect(i * 20 + j % 2 * 10,j * 10,10,10);
    }
  }
  oscctx.fill();

  var pattern = ctx2.createPattern(osc,"no-repeat");

  ctx2.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx2.arc(200,200,100,0,6);
  ctx2.fill();
</script>
```

Which one is more efficient and better to be run hundreds of times per frame?

---

Another edit:

I spent about an hour messing around with it on a sandbox website, and I made this small project:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/-/6446241383661568

There I run each one every millisecond and see how quickly each one updates to see which appears more efficient. `clip()` is on top while `CanvasPattern` is on the bottom. They both appear to be *incredibly* fast to me, and I feel that no matter which I chose I will have almost exactly the same results. However, `clip()` does still appear to be a *bit* faster as far as I can tell.

See for yourself and let me know what you think!

Comment: [`ctx.clip()`](https://jsfiddle.net/b5hm4xs6/) should be the fastest way in the 2D API if we assume a lot of independent elements to be rendered in the same frame every frames. WebGL can probably do a lot better anyway, but depending on your true use-case there might also be some "smart" ways of dealing with it. And for the record, CSS composites layers.

Comment: I looked into `clip()`. Seems very cool, can't believe I had never heard of it before! I will certainly pursue that heavily and see if it can work for what I need. Thank you very much for the advice! As for `"And for the record, CSS composites layers."` I'm not sure I follow what you mean? I went and refreshed myself on the way the browser performs rendering cycles, and I don't see how its "layering" nature relates to my post? Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Kaiido I've been looking into this more, and I've come across `CanvasPattern`. I could implement `CanvasPattern` more easily and quickly into my existing infrastructure, and would prefer to do that over using `clip()` if at all possible. Do you feel that using `CanvasPattern` paired with an OSC would be much slower than using `clip()` or do you think I could get away with it without substantial FPS drops?

Comment: @Kaiido I edited my question to include more detail. Could you take another look at my question and see if you could help me come to the best conclusion? Thanks a ton.

Comment: Once again the problem is that it will depend entirely of what you are drawing... For instance the last link you provided could be overran by globalCompositeOperation (gCO), since only three paint operations are needed. In my example however, we need to perform two paints per object, gCO here is a no way and clip or CanvasPattern will be better. So the only one who can say which is better is you, by measuring **your real** code on different machines. Beware that your test with 1ms delay doesn't say anything. You are only measuring the time spent on the CPU. Most of the work is on the GPU.

Comment: So, you're saying that using gCO would be good so long as each "shape" only requires one pain operation? If you build one shape using multiple operations will it cause unwanted effects where the shapes overlap? I had never even heard of gCO, now I need to go test that a whole bunch and see if that's even better than what I already have planned! Thanks for everything, you've been very helpful. Your comments pointed me to exactly what I needed to solve my issue, I really appreciate that.

Comment: No, gCO is good when there is no need for a lot of paints. Your last example only requires three paints in total: a single `fill()` for the stars, one fillRect()-pattern + "source-in" for the checkboard and one "destination-over" for the yellow background. In these conditions it can compete with the other methods. But in my first example where each shapes had their own color, gCO wouldn't do good.